# clear specific grid's children

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

Let say I have grid:

```
Grid ctGdLanguag
```

and I added the button children to it.

```
TextBlock t = new TextBlock();
Button b = new Button();
ctGdLanguage.Children.Add(b);
ctGdLanguage.Children.Add(t);
```

And I know the method:

```
 ctGdLanguage.Children.Clear()
```

which clear all the child of `ctGbLanguage` grid.

But My question is that is it possible to delete only button children?
I want to leave the `TextBlock` children and clear the Button is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy enough with some simple LINQ:

```
var buttons = ctGdLanguag.Children.OfType<Button>().ToList();

foreach (var button in buttons)
    ctGdLanguag.Children.Remove(button);
```

`OfType<Button>()` includes only the children of type `Button` (or a subtype). 
 `ToList()` copies the buttons into a separate list so you can iterate over them while you modify the grid's `Children` collection.

Comment: you are the best

Answer (score 0):

If you know the specific element name then you can use the Remove() method

```
TextBlock t = new TextBlock();
Button b = new Button();
ctGdLanguage.Children.Add(b);
ctGdLanguage.Children.Add(t);
ctGdLanguage.Children.Remove(b);
```